# Como testear el codigo en Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

tengo que testear el codigo que tengo de una pequeña aplicación en Ruby. Quería hacerlo de forma automática con Sonarqube, pero veo que no soporta Ruby. Le he instalado un plugin para Ruby, pero se queda el programa colgado. 
Entonces quería ahora probar de forma más sencilla directamente con ruby, pues veo que se me ha generado una carpeta: "test" y me ha generado los test de mis controllers y models. Ahora la pregunta es como puedo correr estos tests? Hay un comando específico? y hay otra alternativa de generar test de forma sencilla y profesional?
Gracias!

Comment: fijate si con la info del manual http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html podes armar un test y vemos donde te trabas

Comment: Gracias. Creo que esto me puede ayudar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para correr esos archivos podrias usar los siguientes comandos

Si tienes rails 5 para correr todas tus pruebas dentro de la carpeta test:

```
rails test
```

Una prueba especifica dentro de la carpeta test/models:

```
rails test test/models/NOMBREARCHIVO.rb
```

Para rails 4 los comandos son:

```
bundle exec rake test

bundle exec rake test test/models/NOMBREARCHIVO.rb
```

Para mas informacion de testing.http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html

Si usas rails 4 esta [otra liga](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/testing.html) te puede servir

Comment: Gracias Roxdurazo, con el comando para ruby 5 funciona genial. Ahora tengo creo que deberia de añadir casos para poder testearlos mas a fondo.

Comment: @user87071 asi es!!! checa este link http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html

Comment: Hola Roxdurazo,

Comment: Hola Roxdurazo, me podrías indicar porfavor como puedo añadir un caso para correr un test? es que siempre me sale todo correcto cuando hago el test de los modelos, por ejemplo, tengo un test llamado: contacto_test.rb donde está la opción de crear un contacto nuevo, borrar y actualizar. Como debería crear un test para comprobar que efectivamente me puede crear, borrar y editar? hasta ahora solo hago: rails test test/models/contacto_test.rb y me sale: finishe in 0.002992s, 0.000runs, 0.000 assertions, 0 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips. Es que nunca lo he realizado. Gracias

Comment: Si claro mira dentro  de tu archivo contacto_test.rb ahi puedes definir tus pruebas te paso este ejemplo https://gist.github.com/roseliux/6d429ca441f3ee20b924166f155c5af3

Comment: Si buscas aprender minitest te aconsejo leas el github oficial y googles tus dudas https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest

Comment: Hola Roxdurazo, gracias por tu contestacion. Curiosamente y para test tan básicos, me sale un error: Expected false to be truthy. Que significa esto? porque no me pasa el test si tan solo se trata de comprobar si guarda, modifica y borra? en el fondo estas acciones las hace la aplicación sin problemas y me deberia pasar el test...

Comment: No sabria decirte porque no te pasan las pruebas la verdad sin ver bien tu codigo, tendras tu base de datos de testing creada? usas fixtures?

Comment: Expected false to be truthy. Que significa esto?  quiere decir que la prueba esperaba un true y regreso false tu assert.

Comment: si, algo asi, pero yo tampoco lo tengo claro.

Comment: empieza a leer todo lo que puedas y ver videos sobre minitest.

Comment: Si, gracias! estoy en ello :)